# Regex to replace string not in quotes in IntelliJ

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'm not very good at regex stuff, but what I'm trying to do is replace anything that matches

action: something

where the something is not inside of either single or double quotes.

I want to replace this with action: "something".

So, it should not replace action: "something" or action: 'something' since those already contain quotes. The something could be any word, so it's not static. The action: piece will always be static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use capture groups to accomplish this:

```
action: (\w+)
```

And replace with:

```
action: "$1"
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/sP4pP7

```
action: something
//becomes
action: "something"
```

Obviously if you want something more sophisticated (non-word characters) it changes. You could use something like this:

```
^action: ([.-\w]+)$
```

Which will ensure the string begins with `action:` (via `^`), and `any word-character,  period, or dash` until the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: It seems you missed a comma there.

Comment: @jackrabbit LOL, no I typed `,` and then wrote `comma` ... *goes to get caffeine*

Answer (score 0):

you can use backreference

```
Pattern PATT = Pattern.compile("action:(\\w+)");
    System.out.println(PATT.matcher("test action:word").replaceFirst("action:\"$1\""));
    System.out.println(PATT.matcher(" bla action:\"quoted\" bla").replaceFirst("action:\"$1\""));
```